# Using default ASP.Net MVC setup, how do I Sign in using a Microsoft Account?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0

Why do I continuously receive "The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid."?

My site is hosted in Azure.  I'm trying to Login via the Microsoft sign-in button.  I haven't really made many changes from the default ASP.Net MVC out-of-the-box template.  All I've really changed was to uncomment the `app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication` line and add the **clientId** and **clientSecret**.

Do I have the Redirect URL set up incorrectly?

> Site:  http://mysite.azurewebsites.net
>
> Redirect URL:  http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/

I read somewhere that you need to specify a Redirect URL in the form of `http://www.mysite.azurewebsites.net`.  Can anyone confirm or deny that?  I do not need the **www** in my current set up.

The error I consistently receive is:

> https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches the redirect URI registered for this client application.&state=SomeLongPossiblyEncryptedString

This message is displayed on the page returned after an attempt to login:

**Microsoft Account**

We're unable to complete your request

Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

**3/26/2014 Update: No luck so far, here's some screen shots of my settings in case it helps.**
*Basic Information*

[image]

*API Settings*

[image]

Is this a problem on Microsoft's side or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: for a mobile service, I had to add two redirect urls; one with jsut the domain and another with full path:https://service.azure-mobile.net/login/microsoftaccount

Comment: @Lee_Nover I tried adding that as another redirect (well, http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/login/microsoftaccount), but it did not work.  I do not see a method called microsoftaccount when I search the project.

Comment: I just tried and removed the second url (/login/microsoftaccount) and it stopped working. Added it back and it's working. Did you check the Application Logo and Privacy policy url in "Basic Information"?

in MobileServices.Web-1.1.3.js on line 1506, there's:

var client = login.getMobileServiceClient();
var startUri = _.url.combinePathSegments(
  client.applicationUrl,
  loginUrl,
  provider);

which in end produces "https://service.azure-mobile.net/login/microsoftaccount" and that is passed as the callback uri to the auth provider.

Comment: Would you consider trying a way easier Social Authentication package? https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication  <-- that has a NuGet package that include Windows Live (http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=simpleauthentication)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the default MVC what works for me (just tested about 5 minutes ago) for the redirect URL is

http://testcrap.azurewebsites.net/**signin-microsoft**

All the documentation I've found says to use

http://testcrap.azurewebsites.net/**login/microsoftaccount**

But that doesn't work for me...
**signin-microsoft** does

[image]

OR if that doesn't work then use something like firebug to see what the request to the oauth provider looks like and then whatever the redirecturi is inside of that request is what you need to use..

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this saved my day. This is even true when I tried from Windows store App. :)

Answer (score 5):

For web application you need to set the redirect url in the Live Connect Developer Center.

In API Settings->Redirect URLs you must set:

http://www.yourdomain.com/signin-microsoft

Hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the redirect url in the [Live Connect Developer Center](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index). I've attached a screenshot. This is part of the application validation to prevent malicious applications.

[image: Redirect URL - Microsoft Account]

Comment: Thank you for validating that I need to set the Redirect URL.  Unfortunately I still receive the "The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid." message.

Comment: Are you sure that the URL from which the request originates exactly matches that in the config screen? You're not using HTTPS?

Comment: I tried http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login and it produced the same error.  This is the page that has the Microsoft sign in control.  I'm not using HTTPS, yet.  (I haven't gotten that far yet, this is Step 1.)

Comment: Turn off the 'Mobile or Desktop Client App' setting.

Comment: I tried it with "Mobile or Desktop Client App" On and also Off.  Same result.  "We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later."

Comment: I've verified that it works in my project and done some other testing, so I can't see anything wrong with what's posted here. Could you post your code and config file so we can take a look at that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems Microsoft change the url again. This what works for me

.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback

My redirect url is
https://yyyyyyyy.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback

To get this url, use Fiddler or any http debug tool and look for request to login.live.com. The redirect_url is in the query string.

https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=00000000551716B9&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyyyyyyyyyy.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Fmicrosoftaccount%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=wl.basic+wl.offline_access+wl.signin+wl.birthday+wl.calendars+wl.calendars_update+wl.contacts_birthday+wl.contacts_create+wl.contacts_calendars+wl.contacts_photos+wl.contacts_skydrive+wl.emails+wl.events_create&state=nonce%3Dfe7e6b678b8844f48f079cceadf1f426_20151206145117%26redir%3D%2F

Answer (score 1):

Since I need 3 more reputation points to write a comment to your post I have to ask it here. Sorry about that.
Are you getting this error while trying it out on the real domain or while testing it from your localhost?

If the second is the case you need to setup a DNS entry for a dummy hostname in your local host file that points to 127.0.0.1 and use that dummy name when registering with live. Furthermore it needs IIS, not IIS Express.

Not sure if it is a clean way nor if it is complete, but it is the furthest I got when trying out the new ASP.NET Identitiy Provider. Sadly there is only a example in the official documentation which shows how to use it with google...
I, too, would appreciate a clean answer to this.

Comment: I am using a real domain.  One provided by Microsoft (http://mysite.azurewebsites.net).

Answer (score 0):

Redirect URIs are "SSL sensitive" and you probably always want the SSL version.